# How to solve $L = (1.463 \cdot 10^7R^2)/(F^2V) - 1.463R$ for $R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not the best at math, but feel especially dumb that I can't rearrange this simple formula to solve for Radius $R$ instead of length $L$. Here is the formula:

$$L = \frac {1.463 \cdot 10^7R^2} {F^2V} - 1.463R$$

It took me like 30 minutes to properly format this, lol. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quadratic equation in $R$, so simply apply the quadratic formula. Let $a = \frac{1.463\times 10^7}{F^2V}$. Then:

$$
L = aR^2-1.463R \\
aR^2-1.463R-L = 0 \\
R = \frac{ 1.463 \pm \sqrt{1.463^2+4aL} }{ 2a}
$$

Comment: very cool, thanks